Show CI/CD Status overview of all repositories
I created a GitHub Organization with 10 Repositories. Eeach of them has own CI/CD GitHub Actions Pipeline.
The Problem is, if something not work on staging, I need to open each repository manualy and check its GitHub Action.
In e.g Jenkins for this case, I have an overview over all projects and see the status of the pipleline. How Can I enable equivalent feature on GitHub? Like
  repository 1 - PASSED
  repository 2 - PASSED
  repository 3 - FAILED

or somthing like that, I think everyone understand what I mean.
Solution
You need to edit:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DASHBOARD_TOKEN }}
      ORGANIZATION_NAME: YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NAME

Create a GitHub Classic Token with Repository Access like Status. Name it: DASHBOARD_TOKEN
Create a GitHub Action in orgonizations /.github Repository.
name: Update Dashboard

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/15 * * * *'  # Runs every 15 minutes


jobs:
  update-dashboard:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      actions: read
      checks: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install PyGithub

      - name: Update dashboard
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DASHBOARD_TOKEN }}
          ORGANIZATION_NAME: YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NAME
        run: |
          python - <<EOF
          import os
          from github import Github
          from datetime import datetime

          # Initialize GitHub client
          g = Github(os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN'])
          
          # Get the organization
          org = g.get_organization("$ORGANIZATION_NAME")

          # Get all repositories in the organization
          repos = org.get_repos()

          # Prepare the dashboard content
          dashboard = "# CI/CD Dashboard\n\n"
          dashboard += "| Repository | Workflow | Status | Last Run |\n"
          dashboard += "| ---------- | -------- | ------ | -------- |\n"
          
          for repo in repos:
              workflows = repo.get_workflows()
              for workflow in workflows:
                  runs = workflow.get_runs(status='completed')
                  if runs.totalCount > 0:
                      latest_run = runs[0]
                      status = latest_run.conclusion.lower()
                      
                      # Create status badge
                      if status == 'success':
                          badge = f"![Success](https://img.shields.io/badge/Success-brightgreen)"
                      elif status == 'failure':
                          badge = f"![Failure](https://img.shields.io/badge/Failure-red)"
                      else:
                          badge = f"![{status.capitalize()}](https://img.shields.io/badge/{status.capitalize()}-yellow)"
                      
                      # Format last run date
                      last_run = latest_run.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                      
                      dashboard += f"| [{repo.name}]({repo.html_url}) | {workflow.name} | {badge} | {last_run} |\n"
          
          # Add update timestamp
          dashboard += f"\n\n*Last updated: {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}*"

          # Update the README.md file
          repo = g.get_repo("$ORGANIZATION_NAME/.github")
          contents = repo.get_contents("profile/README.md")
          repo.update_file(contents.path, "Update dashboard", dashboard, contents.sha)

          print("Dashboard updated successfully!")
          EOF


You may add the links of the GHA workflows badges of all your repos in the organization's README for a quick overview. See https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/customizing-your-organizations-profile.

There are many open source tools that you can use:
https://github.com/chriskinsman/github-action-dashboard
https://github.com/marketplace/octolense-github-actions-dashboard
https://github.com/otto-de/gitactionboard
If you want to do it by yourself so as Azeem said, you can use the organization's README file for track the workflows, there is a workflow that run each 15 mins (you can change it) and update the dashboard:
name: Update Dashboard

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/15 * * * *'  # Runs every 15 minutes


jobs:
  update-dashboard:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      actions: read
      checks: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install PyGithub

      - name: Update dashboard
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          ORGANIZATION_NAME: your-organization
        run: |
          python - <<EOF
          import os
          from github import Github
          from datetime import datetime

          # Initialize GitHub client
          g = Github(os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN'])
          
          # Get the organization
          org = g.get_organization("$ORGANIZATION_NAME")

          # Get all repositories in the organization
          repos = org.get_repos()

          # Prepare the dashboard content
          dashboard = "# CI/CD Dashboard\n\n"
          dashboard += "| Repository | Workflow | Status | Last Run |\n"
          dashboard += "| ---------- | -------- | ------ | -------- |\n"
          
          for repo in repos:
              workflows = repo.get_workflows()
              for workflow in workflows:
                  runs = workflow.get_runs(status='completed')
                  if runs.totalCount > 0:
                      latest_run = runs[0]
                      status = latest_run.conclusion.lower()
                      
                      # Create status badge
                      if status == 'success':
                          badge = f"![Success](https://img.shields.io/badge/Success-brightgreen)"
                      elif status == 'failure':
                          badge = f"![Failure](https://img.shields.io/badge/Failure-red)"
                      else:
                          badge = f"![{status.capitalize()}](https://img.shields.io/badge/{status.capitalize()}-yellow)"
                      
                      # Format last run date
                      last_run = latest_run.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                      
                      dashboard += f"| [{repo.name}]({repo.html_url}) | {workflow.name} | {badge} | {last_run} |\n"
          
          # Add update timestamp
          dashboard += f"\n\n*Last updated: {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}*"

          # Update the README.md file
          repo = g.get_repo("$ORGANIZATION_NAME/.github")
          contents = repo.get_contents("profile/README.md")
          repo.update_file(contents.path, "Update dashboard", dashboard, contents.sha)

          print("Dashboard updated successfully!")
          EOF

Result:


Let say I want to do it by my self. Im not sure that I understand it correct. Where I need to paste that script? Into a README.MD of the organization? Or should I paste it into .github Repository as GitHub Action?

@Tristate no, it's a github action workflow script, you need out it under .github/workflows folder, like any workflow

That actions runs now successful. But on the updated readme I see a table: CI/CD Dashboard
that is empty. Do I need manually add Repositories somewhere? As I understand your script it shoul load all orga. repos automaticly..?

Yea, it should load all, what you see in the logs? and maybe you need grand permissions in other repos

I created a classic github token, with status permissions. And replaced GITHUB_TOKEN with my Token. Now its working
